# how can I separate the data from an input with php

Tags: php

If I typed multi lines in an input how can I separate the lines 
ex : if o typed multiple emails how can I use the mail() function for each line
thank you

Comment: *"for each"* - You basically (almost) answered it yourself. You just need to separate those now ;-)

Comment: Please share the code?

Comment: I know I answered the question but it wont work with inputs it works with arrays ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP :

```
$lines = preg_split('/\r\n|[\r\n]/', $_POST['input']);
foreach($line as $lines){
//do whatever with line ex 
mail($line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) should provide the answer. If you want to send a seperate email to each address, where the addresses are seperated by a newline, you will want to use `\n` as the seperator, and pass it, as well as the string, to `explode()`. `\n` is the escape sequence for a newline, which means it is an alias for a newline.

NOTE: Escape sequences like `\n` only work in double quotes (`"`). The only exceptions where escape sequences work in single quotes (`'`) are `\\` and `\'`

Here is some example code, that uses a `for` loop:

```
$inputData //This stores your input data that has newlines

$data = explode("\n", $inputData)
$lenOfData = count($data) //These two lines stop us from re-executing count() and explode(), so we only run it once

for($i = 0; i < count($inputData); $i++){
    mail($data[$i], "We have released a new product", "Description of product");
}
```

Note the use of the two intermidiate variables to avoid re-evaluating the `explode` and `count` functions.

Alternatively, you can use a [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) instead of a for loop, and then the code would look like (again with `$inputData` storing the mailing list)

```
$data = explode("\n", $inputData)

for($data as $i){
    mail($i, "We have released a new product", "Description of product");
}
```